# ERROR: Unable to start TLS: SSL connect attempt failed error:14090086

Tags: zimbra

I ran the command:

```
zmcontrol status
```

on my zimbra server, and I got the error:

```
Unable to start TLS: SSL connect attempt failed error:14090086:SSL routines:ssl3_get_server_certificate:certificate verify failed when connecting to ldap master.
Cannot determine services - exiting
```

I checked my server and everything seems normal: SSL certificate is valid, system date is correct, Mail server still works well.

But I get that error every time I run command check status.

Service error on admin console:
[image: service error on admin console]

Answer (score 1):

```
zmlocalconfig -e ldap_starttls_supported=0
zmcontrol restart
```

Answer (score 0):

I have solved by running the following commands from cli, logged in with 'zimbra' user:

```
    zmlocalconfig -e ldap_starttls_required=false
    zmlocalconfig -e ldap_starttls_supported=0
    zmcontrol restart
```

Answer (score 0):

Reinstalling a certificate solved the problem for me, since the error is because it expires.

Comment: I removed the part which should have been a comment on an existing answer. Compare https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead